# How/Where do you store git repositories when working with multiple servers?

Tags: git, project-management, gitosis, staging

I'm fairly new to git, but I'm trying to set it up across all of our systems so that all projects are managed by git and gitosis.

My question has to do with location of the actual repositories when considering the development / staging / production servers.

Should I...

A) Set up git and gitosis on 1 server to host all of my git repositories and pull down the appropriate repository to each place it's needed (three servers and multiple local computers).

```
<Dev Server [git gitosis > myproject.git]> 
<Staging Server [git clone ...]> 
<Production Server [git clone ...]>
```

OR

B) Set up git and gitosis on all servers so that git repositories are hosted on the same server as their respective project, commit to each server down the line as the project is passed from Local to Development to Staging to Production. In this way, the repositories are only as up to date as what has been approved for that server.

```
<Dev Server [git gitosis > myproject.git]>
<Staging Server [git gitosis > myproject.git {updated from Dev Server}]>
<Production Server [git gitosis > myproject.git {updated from Staging Server}]>
```

As I write this it seems like (A) would be the better option and that the proper releases to each server would be handled by different branches... Not sure if I'm off or not.

If both are incorrect please let me know of the appropriate way to set up git across multiple servers.

It would also be nice to have a quick overview of how managing a system like this would work... for example, use of branches, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd definitely go with the first option; having quick and easy access to all versions of your code everywhere is a good thing.

Comment: And some tagging convention or (remote) branches at the "central" place can help you keep track what is working (checked out) on which host. Also: I think you shouldn't be afraid of committing something locally, and only then pushing these changes to the "central" place; after all, git is distributed, and this is convenient. Then the real state at that individual working place could be reflected by a remote branch (or a tag), as I've said already.

Comment: Should this be a separate server? I have 3 dev servers and 3 staging as virtual machines on one server and 3 separate VPSs from Rackspace for production. I could make an additional virtual machine to host the git repositories... should I do this? Also how would you manage this to make sure you're keeping track of what should/shouldn't be deployed to dev/staging/production... ex. maintain separate branches for dev, staging, and production?

Answer (score 3):

I would go with the first option and would use Gitolite instead of Gitosis. Gitosis is no longer actively developed. Gitolite gives you more features.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well that's silly. Why would anyone propose gitosis over gitolite?

Comment: +1 to put it at 0. This is may be more of a comment than an answer. I was about to say the same thing in a comment on OP, before I saw this here. That said, it's completely true. I wish very much that the gitosis docs said SOMETHING about it being obsolete.

Comment: Odd though because the tutorial under the community Ubuntu documentation says to use gitosis: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Git and that was for 10.04... is it just recently that it became obsolete?

Comment: Obsolete may be a bit strong of a word. "No longer actively developed" would be more accurate from what I've heard in the IRC channel.